# how to make UILabel with HTML format and adjust width based on content

Tags: ios7, uilabel

I'm trying to develop to put HTML text in UILabel and adjust its width based on content just like per attachment. In first image, **100** is as bold and UILabel width is based on its content. In second image, 21 Dec 2015 is as bold and its width is based on content as well. Any solution will be appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you use iOS 7 and above then there is a solution:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSAttributedString_UIKit_Additions/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSAttributedString/initWithData:options:documentAttributes:error:

You need to create `NSAttributedString` and set it to UILabel's `attributedText`.

For sizing you can use UILabel's `sizeToFit` method, it will size label to it's content.

Comment: it's correct. But to use in attributedText, defined font is missing.

Comment: What you mean by defined font ?

Comment: font name I set in Storyborad is missing.